# Travel Path In Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to do some web scraping and I am having some issues with `Python/Scrapy`. 
I have isolated the links that I want to travel to but can't figure out how to go there to scrape more data. What I have so far is something like this:

```
def parse_site(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//a')

    # This part works and is responsible for getting only the links I want
    sites = [site for site in sites if "." in str(site.xpath('text()').extract())]
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = DomainManagerItem()

        dName = str(site.xpath('text()').extract())[3:-2]
        item['domainName'] = dName
```

At this point I want to store information from the next page into the second field of the item. I am trying to do the following. I have the base address stored in `BASE_ADDRESS` and I am pulling the second part of the address by using `newPath = str(site.xpath("@href").extract())` and that works, if I `print` the output of `BASE_ADDRESS + newPath` it is exactly what I am looking for. What I am doing now is trying to get something from the next page by using another module. I can't get it to work, however. It looks something like this.

```
        item['totalUsers'] = self.parse_client(ResponseObj)
```

I am not sure how to get the proper response object and have tried a number of different things. Can't get it to work though. I think I can parse the next file and get the `totalUsers` out of it, It's just a matter of getting it to send to the next module.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post code for parse_client function? What is the value of ResponseObj and where does it come from? Where and how are you calling parse_client? Is parse client making a request for next page? Posting link to website you're crawling can generally help people in answering your question as they can easily test their solutions.

Comment: The problem with posting the website is that it requires an account, so unless people pay for an account they won't be able to use the information unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be some things I just didn't understand about Python and trying to get a grasp on scrapy. Here is the working solution that I used..

```
def parse_site(self, response):
    global BASE_WEBSITE
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//a') # xpath for the sites
    # To get the desc. of the <a> tag use sel.xpath('//a/text()').extract()
    # Get all the websites that would lead to clients.
    sites = [site for site in sites if "." in str(site.xpath('text()').extract())]
   # items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = DomainManagerItem()

        # Get the Description and trim it
        dName = str(site.xpath('text()').extract())[3:-2]

        # Get the Path and trim it
        newPath = "https://" +  BASE_WEBSITE +  (str(site.xpath("@href").extract())[3:-2])

        item['domainName'] = dName
        yield Request(url = newPath, callback = self.parse_client, meta = {'item':item})


def parse_client(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    ite = response.meta['item']
    site = sel.xpath('//td')
    ite['totalUsers'] = str(site[8].xpath('text()').extract())[3:-2]

    return ite
```